# Clear All Data EXCEPT First Row and First Column

Tags: excel, vba

Would like to clear all data except Row 1 and Column A. Am able to clear all except the first row OR first column using something like this:

```
Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
```

But would like to know how to keep both in when clearing. (In the worksheet, the first row and column are both "frozen.")

Comment: `rows` only does the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, clear `B2` to the very last cell:

```
With ActiveSheet
   .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).ClearContents
End With
```